# Java:error static context

Tags: java

buenos dias/tardes/noches, tengo un problema acerca de este codigo de java, quiero invocar los metodos de diferentes clases a una clase pero me aparece este error al poner la variable aux "op", ¿saben a que se refiere con lo de static context?

Dibujos.java:11: error: non-static variable op cannot be referenced from a static context
op = entrada.nextInt();
^
Dibujos.java:12: error: non-static variable op cannot be referenced from a static context
if(op==1)
^
Dibujos.java:16: error: non-static variable op cannot be referenced from a static context
if(op==2)
^

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
       public class Dibujos{

     public int op;
     public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Bievenido al generador de figuras");
    System.out.println("Nuestro programa lepermite generar 2 figuras...Pentagono y rectangulo");
    System.out.println("¿que figura desea formar? 1-Pentagono, 2-Rectangulo");
  op = entrada.nextInt();
    if(op==1)
    {
       Pentagonos.dibujarpentagono();
    }
    if(op==2)
   {
       Rectangulos.dibujarrectangulo();
   }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Las variables de instancia son variables no estáticas y se declaran en una clase fuera de cualquier método, constructor o bloque.

Como las variables de instancia se declaran en una clase, estas variables se crean cuando un objeto de la clase se crea y se destruye cuando se destruye el objeto.

```
  public class Dibujos{
     public int op;//variable de instancia
```

para poder hacer uso de "op" como variable de instancia..

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Dibujos obj=new Dibujos();
    obj.op = entrada.nextInt();
```

Las variables estáticas también se conocen como variables de clase.
Estas variables se declaran de forma similar a las variables de instancia, la diferencia es que las variables estáticas se declaran utilizando la palabra clave `static` dentro de una clase fuera de cualquier constructor o bloque de métodos.
como has declarado "op" como variable de instancia el error te indica de que esta no es estática

solucion:

```
public class Dibujos{
         public static int op;
```

otra solucion seria declara "op" con ámbito local y declararla dentro del `main` y no fuera de ella

```
public static void main(String[]args){
      int op;
```

Comment: no se si me recuerdas de la otra pregunta que me ayudaste a responder pero te agradezco mucho tu ayuda! ya lo comprendi y lo pude adaptar pero me aparece otro error que creo que tiene que ver con algo externo o con el scanner:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Dibujos.main(Dibujos.java:12)

Comment: no, la unica que tengo es la que usa "op" y hasta ahi, y sobre el scanner close, lo probe pero me sigue poniendo el error, lo cerre al final de las condicionales de este modo: entrada.close(); estos usando un compilador online llamado jdoodle

Comment: ya solucione el problema compañero, segun veo era por el compilador, probablemente el compilador online que estaba usando tenia algunos errores con respecto a eso, lo probe con el compilador online GDB y funciono ya, tambien probe tu metodo en el compilador jdoodle(donde aparece el problema) y todavia persiste y leere sobre lo que mandaste de los jdk ya que aun no me han quedado claro

Comment: dicho valor Stdin Inputs debe ser cuando declaro la variable(que seria op) osea de int op=Stdin Inputs?

Comment: no ,hay una casilla llamada Stdin Inputs coloca ahi 1 o 2 y dale execute

Comment: ya veo, si funciono, no esperaba que tenia que hacer eso, pensaba que iba a ser similar a c, que lo ponia directamente en el codigo, te agradezco mucho por tomarte tu tiempo en responder y ayudarme a comprender el "por que" de los problemas que tenia

Comment: Es un proceso de acostumbrarse a algunos cambios ,:) ..si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides darle el ✓ ,saludos

Comment: de echo si lo hice las ultimas 2 veces que me ayudaste pero me manda un mensaje de que como mi reputacion es menor a 15, no puedo votar asi con palomita a tus respuestas, pero segun dice se registran nadamas que no se ven visibles, saludos, te cuidas!!!